# I did a wire transfer from my bank here in US to my client in Turkey but unknown to that his account was Euro account

Tags: united-states, bank-account, international-transfer

I made a wire transfer to my client in Turkey using the swift code and the IBAN and other information, but the problem is that it was unknown to me that the turkey account he gave to me was Euro account and I made the transfer in USD.

Until now, My client didn't receive the wire and they told me that the international transfer may take 4 or 5 days.

What do you think the result will be?

Is there an automatic converting  from Dollar  to Euro, or will the bank in Turkey  refuse to receive the money because they are in a different currency?

Will I lose my money?

Comment: Most likely will be an automatic currency exchange with a small commission. You would have paid a commission to convert the funds on the sending side, too, so probably not much of a difference either way.

Answer (score 3):

There would be automatically conversion of USD to EUR. This is pretty standard in international transfer.